# NameError: undefined - have parsing rules for local variables changed in Ruby 2.1.2?

Tags: ruby, parsing, variable-assignment, local-variables, guard-clause

I am getting `NameError: undefined local variable or method` with ruby 2.1.2

As observed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102804/ruby-variable-scope-and-order-of-parsing-vs-operations-assignment-in-an-if), expressions like:

```
bar if bar = true
```

raises an undefined local variable error (provided that `bar` is not defined prior) because `bar` is read by the parser before it is assigned. And I believe that there used to be no difference with that with this expression:

```
bar if bar = false
```

The difference between the two is whether the main body is evaluated or not, but that should not matter if encountering an undefined local variable immediately raises an error before evaluating the condition.

But when I run the second code on Ruby 2.1.2, it does not raise an error. Has it been like that from before? If so, then what was the parsing discussion all about? If not, has Ruby specification changed? Is there any reference to that?  What did it do in 1.8.7, 1.9.3, etc. ?

Comment: No one seems to be answering the "did it change" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes it changed in ruby 2.1.2

In `1.8.7`, `1.9.3`, `2.0.0` and even `2.1.1` I get 2 warnings and no errors:

```
2.0.0-p247 :007 > bar if bar = false
(irb):7: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
 => nil 
2.0.0-p247 :008 > bar if bar = true
(irb):8: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
 => true
```

whereas in the `2.1.2` version you mention I get 2 warnings and 1 `NameError` error.

```
2.1.2 :001 > bar if bar = true
(irb):1: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.2 :002 > bar if bar = false
(irb):2: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
 => nil
```

This is on my Ubuntu 14

Comment: Thanks for the details. And I suppose you do get an error with 2.1, right?

Comment: Updated with that info.

Comment: Amazing that you can switch between all those versions. I only have the newest one, and your report helps.

Comment: rvm has been the key tool for that for me for about 3 years.  I can just do `rvm use 2.1.2` to switch.  Well worth checking out - http://rvm.io/ or just `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: Some folks have switched to rbenv to manage their ruby versions but rvm does what I need and I haven't seen a reason to switch.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference with regards to whether `bar` is defined or not. In both cases, `bar` is undefined in the body. However, in the latter case, the body is never evaluated, therefore it doesn't matter. You never resolve the name `bar`, therefore you never get an error during name resolution.

Local variables are *defined* when an assignment is *parsed*.
They are *initialized* when an assignment is *executed*.

It's perfectly fine for a variable to be unitialized. It will just evaluate to `nil` in that case:

```
if false
  bar = 42
end

bar
# => nil
```

However, if the variable is *undefined*, then Ruby doesn't know whether a bare word is a local variable or a receiverless argumentless message send:

```
foo
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'
#                                     ^^^^^^^^^
# Ruby doesn't know whether it's a variable or a message send
```

Compare with:

```
foo()
# NoMethodError: undefined method `foo'
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

self.foo
# NoMethodError: undefined method `foo'
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

All together now:

```
foo()
# NoMethodError: undefined method `foo'

self.foo
# NoMethodError: undefined method `foo'

foo
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'

if false
  foo = 42
end

foo
# => nil

foo = :fortytwo

foo
# => :fortytwo
```

The trouble in this particular case is that the order in which the expressions are *parsed* (and thus the order in which variables are defined) *does not* match with the order in which the expressions are *executed*.

The assignment is executed *first*, which would make you assume that `bar` would be defined in the body. But it isn't, because the body was *parsed* first and thus an **I don't know whether this is a method or a variable** node was inserted into the syntax tree *before* the assignment was ever seen.

However, if that node is never interpreted, i.e. the condition is false, then nothing bad will happen.

Comment: You say "unitialized" (typo btw) and that it will "evaluate to `nil`". Would it be wrong to say it's initialized as `nil`? Is it not actually `nil` yet?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on **Ruby 2.1.2**.

Adding with *@Jörg W Mittag* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307074/2767755).

[Another commonly confusing case](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) is when using a modifier `if`:

```
p a if a = 0.zero? # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `a'
```

Rather than printing “true” you receive a NameError, “undefined local variable or method `a’”. Since ruby parses the bare a left of the if first and has not yet seen an assignment to a it assumes you wish to call a method. Ruby then sees the assignment to a and will assume you are referencing a local method.

The confusion comes from the `out-of-order` execution of the expression. First the local variable is assigned-to then you attempt to call a nonexistent method.

Based on *above* explanation -

```
bar if bar = false
```

*simply* returns `nil`, as the expression has been *evaluated* as *false*, the body of the code associated with the `if` modifier wouldn't be executed. `nil` is being returned by any *block* in Ruby, *by default when there is no explicit default value.*